# How can I match more than one Google Calendar extended property with the PHP API?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

The API documentation says that you can match more than one extended property, but you can't add the same key twice to a PHP associative array.

```
$service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client)
$optParams = [
    'maxResults' => 1,
    'sharedExtendedProperty' => 'origin=external',
    'sharedExtendedProperty' => 'key=???',
];

$events = $service->events->listEvents($calendar, $optParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Google Calendar API for PHP, you can submit multiple string values to parameter values. They are converted internally to multiple request URI parameters.

```
$optParams = [
    'maxResults' => 1,
    'sharedExtendedProperty' => ['origin=external', 'key=???'],
];
```